# MS Access SQL Records Disappearing in LEFT JOIN that shouldn't

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am really not understanding why this `LEFT JOIN` is not working the way it should. There are supposed to be 99 records coming from `cleaning_zzz_2016` as is the case when I remove the `LEFT JOIN`. However, when I add the `LEFT JOIN` it drops down to 96. Some of the `CoNumber` don't exist in the `cleaning_zzz_sales` table, so I would expect the those fields to just be blank and the `s.` data to remain; however, it is removing them. I think this may be due to the `WHERE s.Rep = 'ZZZ'`, but I am not 100% sure or how to get around the issue.

```
SELECT j.CoNumber, j.CoName, s.Selling, s.Positions, s.Plans, '' AS Review, j.St, j.CE, j.SI, j.Tgt, ROUND(MAX(j.Comm) * 100) AS [Max of Comm], ROUND(MAX(j.Comm2) * 100) AS [Max of Comm2]
FROM cleaning_zzz_2016 AS j 
LEFT JOIN cleaning_zzz_sales AS s 
  ON j.CoNumber= s.CoNumber
WHERE s.Rep = 'ZZZ' AND s.RepYear = 2016
GROUP BY j.CoNumber, j.CoName, j.St, j.CE, j.SI, j.Tgt, s.Selling, s.Positions, s.Plans
ORDER BY j.CoNumber;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any conditions in the `where` clause will filter out rows outright.  You want to add all conditions on the left joined table directly in the join condition itself. With MS Access, I believe you need to be careful with the parenthesis when you have multiple join conditions.

So I think that the query would look like this:

```
SELECT j.CoNumber, j.CoName, s.Selling, s.Positions, s.Plans, '' AS Review, j.St, j.CE, j.SI, j.Tgt, ROUND(MAX(j.Comm) * 100) AS [Max of Comm], ROUND(MAX(j.Comm2) * 100) AS [Max of Comm2]
FROM cleaning_zzz_2016 AS j 
LEFT JOIN cleaning_zzz_sales AS s 
  ON (j.CoNumber= s.CoNumber
  AND s.Rep = 'ZZZ' 
  AND s.RepYear = 2016)
GROUP BY j.CoNumber, j.CoName, j.St, j.CE, j.SI, j.Tgt, s.Selling, s.Positions, s.Plans
ORDER BY j.CoNumber;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer. Was driving me nuts!

Comment: @user3123109: have you tried the above query in Access? In my opinion Access does not allow having non-joining expressions in the `ON` clause. I think the answer provided by @GordonLinoff below would be the right one for Access

Comment: @cha: You made me doubt, because I answered without having MS Access installed to test it. And based on a quick search, you're right that there are some posts indicating that this should not be possible.  But I just tested with MS Access 2010, and I am able to do it fine.  I wonder if something changed in the later versions of MS Access.  I couldn't find any information that confirms this.

Comment: So the above does work perfectly... however, the issue I am running into now with it is if I save the query and close and then go to open it in design view, or just simply run it,I get an error stating that the join is not supported. This is may do to how Access reformats SQL queries how it wants them. I then can't open the query and have had to manually enter it. I haven't entered the query into VBA yet, so that might get around the issue.

Comment: @user3123109: Yeah, I've had that happen to me too. Access will sometimes mess up the parenthesis. Very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you shouldn't use on `where` columns that are on the right side of the `left join`. Just put those conditions on the `ON`

Comment: Thanks! It was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 1):

The problem are the columns in the `where` clause.  Unfortunately, MS Access doesn't allow constant comparisons in `on`.  You can fix this with a subquery:

```
SELECT j.CoNumber, j.CoName, s.Selling, s.Positions, s.Plans,
       '' AS Review, j.St, j.CE, j.SI, j.Tgt,
       ROUND(MAX(j.Comm) * 100) AS [Max of Comm],
       ROUND(MAX(j.Comm2) * 100) AS [Max of Comm2]
FROM cleaning_zzz_2016 AS j LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT s.*
      FROM cleaning_zzz_sales AS s 
      WHERE s.Rep = 'ZZZ' AND s.RepYear = 2016
     ) s
     ON j.CoNumber= s.CoNumber
GROUP BY j.CoNumber, j.CoName, j.St, j.CE, j.SI, j.Tgt, s.Selling, s.Positions, s.Plans
ORDER BY j.CoNumber;
```

Comment: I will have to give this a try. While the other suggestions about referring to the constants in the `ON` statement do work, if the query is saved and closed, and then reopened in either design view or just run, it results in a `JOIN IS NOT SUPPORTED` error which effectively locks you out, so you have to rewrite the query. Haven't moved it into VBA yet which is where it ultimately should be, so not sure what the behavior is like there yet.